# How to know the status of a ticket using REST in CAS OVERLAY 5.3?

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, single-sign-on, cas, netflix-zuul

I have centralized the authentication of my clients (Python, JAVA GWT, JAVA Spring) using CAS OVERLAY which is done correctly; My problem is, how can I know the status of a ticket to validate my session from any of my clients? I have reviewed and there is a GET type REST service but the truth is I don't know if I am using it correctly.

Client 1 active session with ticket: (Python)
[image]
Now to verify the ticket use:

[image]

Can you guide me through this problem or is there a better way to validate a ticket for my client-side session?

ADD:
[image]

segun https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html my ticket is invalid but I don't understand this context

> "the ticket did not come from an initial login"

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

> How to know the status of a ticket using REST in CAS OVERLAY 5.3?

If you look at the [REST documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html#ticket-status), you'll observe this:

> Verify the status of an obtained ticket to make sure it still is valid and has not yet expired.
>
> `GET /cas/v1/tickets/TGT-fdsjfsdfjkalfewrihfdhfaie HTTP/1.0`

This requires that you turn on REST support, as indicated by [the same documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html#configuration).